# Have anyone had is kind of error before and how to fix it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This happened when updating text area.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a **valid EF model** with the correct field length, this shouldn't be a problem (for example, by decorating with Length attributes)

This type of error generally occurs when you try to put characters or values more than what you have specified in your table schema.
Like in that case: you specify `varchar(10)`, but you are trying to store a value that contains 19 characters.

Solution:

- Check your parameter sizes against column sizes and the field(s)
- Try updating each property one by one with a `.SaveChanges()` to find out which one is causing the error.

Comment: Thank you @Mohi, I checked the database the field  was set as nvarchar(1000)

Comment: @Saranya so problem solved or not?

Comment: I planned to set maxlength to the textarea and add text count down below the textarea and test it today. that is my plan. Thanks for point me to the right direction.

Comment: Yes, I set maxlength to the textarea so it did solved the problem. Thank you for your help.